# displaying item with an Iterator in ADF

Tags: iterator

I am experiencing the following problem... I am developing ADF applications and I am using in this case, a panelFormLayout with 3 rows and 3 columns... Inside of it an af:iterator which shows 9 items, each one inside a panelGroupLayout... I notice that although I use a TreeSet to order my item collection, I get my items displayed as follows...

```
Name1 - Name4 - Name7
Name2 - Name5 - Name8
Name3 - Name6 - Name9
```

and I want them to display as follows...

```
Name1 - Name2 - Name3
Name4 - Name5 - Name6
Name7 - Name8 - Name9
```

Dows anyone has an idea of how to solve this ?. Thankx

Comment: Hey did this work ? pls mark q as answered if yes.

Answer (score 0):

You the panelFormLayout set to Horizontal inside of a panelGroupLayout set to vertical. This would mean that for every 3 values given by the iterator, it would be a new row.